# Power BI does not recognize already created measure in another measure in the same table

Tags: powerbi

I am following a tutorial to learn DAX.
I have a DAX measure called Yearly Profit Margin which is calculated as:

```
Yearly Profit Margin = 'Sales in USD'[Gross Revenue USD] / 'Sales in USD'[Net Revenue USD]
```

In the next step it is calculating the Quarterly Profit by using this formula

```
Quarterly Profit = CALCULATE([Yearly Profit Margin], DATESQTD('CalendarTable'[Date]))
```

However, my Power BI formula bar shows an error saying that "The value for 'Yearly Profit Margin' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column."  but this is the one I have created in the earlier step. From the screenshot given in the tutorial it does not show any error but in my case it is showing the error with red lines. Please help me in sorting out the issue.

[This is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsjn2.jpg)

I tried renaming the measure, adding column with the same name, but to no use.

Comment: This is the model I am using. https://imgur.com/C7NNYdx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Yearly Profit Margin` is created as a Calculated Column and not as a Measure.

Delete it and create a new **Measure** with:

```
Yearly Profit Margin = 
  DIVIDE(
    SUM( 'Sales in USD'[Gross Revenue USD] ),
    SUM( 'Sales in USD'[Net Revenue USD] )
  )
```

See [Field list icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-field-list#field-list-icons) for the field icon meanings.